# How to determine volume from AVAudioBuffer audio sample

Tags: ios, avaudioengine

I am attempting to write a small demonstration application that will do some audio measurements (volume and pitch) in realtime.

I've got, I think, to the point where I have the audio samples, but I am new to working with audio and not sure where to go next. Is there a way to determine pitch and volume of a particular sample as a function of the float/integer/byte value of the samples?

Also, I had to add this line "buffer.frameLength = 1" to get the code to run. When I print the variable "inputFormat", I get the value "".

All the material+tutorials that I can find about audio processing (in general and on ios) seems to require a lot of contextual info they leave out.

The code written in swift works to get the samples, and outputs Sample: (~ -8 to +8 float value).

```
func test() {

  let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
  let inputFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)

    let bufferSize = 10

  inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(bufferSize), format: inputFormat) { (buffer, time) in

       buffer.frameLength = 1

       var i = 0;
       while i < Int(buffer.frameLength) && buffer.floatChannelData != nil
       {
         let sample : Double = Double(buffer.floatChannelData![i].pointee)
         print("\nSample: "+String(sample))
         i += 1
       }

   }

   audioEngine.prepare()
   do {
      try audioEngine.start()
   }catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a fast Fourier transform is? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iOS+fast+Fourier+transform

Comment: No, but will look into it. I've realized that individual audio samples don't have pitch. I'll need to build off a sample app (looking around).